# Cant insert character values from textbox to database

Tags: c#, .net, sql, ado.net

Trying to Insert into database from textboxes, but it will only accept integers and not characters - what could the problem be?

```
 string sCMD = string.Format("INSERT INTO [Table] ([Item], [Des1],[Des2], [Prodline], [ANR], [STime]) VALUES({0},{1},'0',{2},{3},{4})"
            ,txtText1.Text, txtText2.Text, txText3.Text, txtText4.Text, txtText5.Text);
```

The name "" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

Comment: what are the columnsin DB table?

Comment: Imagine what will happen if a user enters `some"valu"e` in your textbox.

Comment: Is your database allowing char/varchar on that specific column? And what database are you using?

Comment: Rather than assembling the query and the *data* as a string (either using concatenation, or as here, using formatting) you ought to use parameters. Search for `<your database product> <your programming language> parameters` ought to find some decent results.

Comment: What values are you passing to the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something to consider:

```
using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    c.Open();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Table] ([Item], [Des1],[Des2], [Prodline], [ANR], [STime]) VALUES(@Item,@Des1,'0',@ProdLine,@ANR,@STime)", c))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item", txtText1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Des1", txtText2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProdLine", txText3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ANR", txtText4.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STime", txtText5.Text);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

If you were to send the SQL statement you're building to the server it might look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO [Table] ([Item], [Des1],[Des2], [Prodline], [ANR], [STime])
VALUES(Item Name,Here is my description.,'0',Prod line,ANR value,some time)
```

Clearly that's going to fail. It's not even surrounding the values with single quotes. Now, all of them may not be character, I get that, but you get my point.

But to add insult to injury it's wide open to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection) the way you have it written. With the parameterized approach it's not.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very dangerous line of code.

For starters, you are creating a string with no delimiters whatsoever for the values, which means that the only values that could pass withour issue are integers. Anything else needs to be delimited, which you don't do in this String.Format statement.

Worse, you are trying to create a sql statement from direct user input. Any weird value can cause your code to fail, or worse, cause execution of unwanted code. Imagine what would happen in a user entered eg `'sdf','sdfs',sdf'` as the FIRST value. The resulting string would have 3 correct values for the first three columns that came from the first textboxt.

Now image what would happen if the user entered something like `'blablabla';DROP TABLE sometable;--`. This would cause the `Delete` command to execute. This is a standard SQL injection attack scenario.

There are many more problems, eg when you try to pass numbers with floats, dates or any type whose conversion to string depends on your locale.

Instead of trying to construct a SQL query by string concatenation, you should use parameterized queries, as described in [Give me parameterized SQL or give me death](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). The resulting code is easier to write, performs much faster, has no conversion errors and is not subject to SQL injection attacks,